# CiviCase extension not displaying non-case activities in contact summary screen

Tags: extension, civicase

Ive installed the CiviCase extension - ie the one provided by colemanw, version 5.

Works fine, except on the normal activities tab. Clicking on that loads placeholders for the default listing, which is all activities - but they are not populated.

Selecting an activity type eg meeting populates fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Using 5.46.2

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce and it sounds like maybe the extension hasn't kept up with some core changes? I'd file an issue at https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.civicase/issues

`User deprecated function: Deprecated function Civi\Angular\AngularLoader::setModules, use addModules`

`Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined`